# Differential equation in spectral domain - meaning?

Tags: fourier-transform, differential-equations

Is there any occurrence of ODEs in spectral domain?
Let me mark the words: an ODE that applies to the Fourier transforms of functions describing a physical phenomena.

That is distinct from spectral theory that applies to ODEs in real domain, I believe.

Edit : to be more specific, an equation of type 
$$ a\frac{d^2F(\omega)}{d\omega^2}+b\frac{dF(\omega)}{d\omega}+cF(\omega)=0 $$

$F(\omega)$ being the Fourier transform of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different answer in case you mean an ODE in the Fourier variables. If the ODE is to be, say, linear in the Fourier domain then its counterpart in the real domain must have coefficients that are polynomials in $x$ or $t$. I couldn't think of a situation where this occurs "naturally". Regardless, we can build our own situation. Consider waves propagating along an inhomogeneous beam. The hypothetical beam is made of a light material in the center and of increasingly heavy materials as you move away from the center say with a mass density that is quadratic in $x$. Then, the wave equation, in arbitrary units, can be $\partial_{x}^2 u = (1+x^2)\partial_{t}^2u$ for instance, or in Fourier domain: $-k^2u = -\omega^2u + \omega^2\partial_k^2 u$.

Comment: Thank you Hussein. Apologies for the long delay in answering. I edited my question to clarify. I'm not sure I understand well your notation. Your u below is the Fourier transform with respect to which variable?

Comment: $u$ is transformed with respect to both $x$ and $t$; the ODE as you can see is in $k$ rather than $\omega$. This can be fixed if you let the beam’s properties change polynomially in time rather than in space.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example. In the early universe, the [density perturbations](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/Cosmology/Chapter4.pdf) $\delta({{\bf x}, t}) = 1 - \rho({{\bf x}, t}) /\overline{\rho}(t)$ evolve according to the expression

$$
\frac{\partial^2\delta}{\partial t^2} + 2\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial t} = 4\pi G\overline{\rho}\delta + \frac{c_S^2}{a^2}\nabla^2\delta + \frac{2}{3}\frac{\overline{T}}{a^2}\nabla^2 S \tag{1}
$$

where $a$ is the [scale factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations), $\overline{T}$ the average temperature, $c_S$ the sound speed, and $S$ the entropy. It is convenient to write

$$
\delta({\bf x}, t)= \sum_{{\bf k}}\delta_{\bf k}(t)e^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}} \tag{2}
$$

which leads to

$$
\frac{{\rm d}^2\delta_{\bf k}}{{\rm d}t^2} + 2 \frac{\dot{a}}{a} \frac{{\rm d}\delta_{\bf k}}{{\rm d}t} = \left[4\pi G\overline{\rho} - \frac{k^2 c_S^2}{a^2}\right]\delta_{\bf k} - \frac{2}{3}\frac{\overline{T}}{a^2}k^2S_{\bf k} \tag{3}
$$

which has several advantages. One of them, is that in the linear regime, all modes are decoupled.

> Application: Gravitational instability

If the evolution of each mode is adiabatic, then $S_{\bf k} = 0$ and in a static universe Eq. (3) becomes

$$
\frac{{\rm d}^2\delta_{\bf k}}{{\rm d}t^2} = -\omega_{\bf k} \delta_{\bf k} ~~~\mbox{with}~~~ \omega_{\bf k} = \frac{k^2c_S^2}{a^2} - 4\pi G\overline{\rho} \tag{5}
$$

Define the characteristic length

$$
\lambda_J = \frac{2\pi a}{k_J} = c_S\left(\frac{\pi}{G\overline{\rho}}\right)^{1/2} \tag{6}
$$

which just represents the length traveled by a sound-wave in a [gravitational free-fall time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-fall_time). For $\lambda < \lambda_J$ it is clear that $\omega^2_{\bf k} > 0$ and the solution oscillates, that is, for the amplitude of perturbation oscillate in time. However a different story happens for $\lambda > \lambda_J$ in this case this $\omega^2_{\bf k} < 0$ and the perturbation will grow with time.

And this is pretty much how [galaxies form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeans_instability)!

Comment: Thank you caverac. Apologies for the long delay in answering. I think I understand your answer, but I didn't formulate my question well enough initially. I edited it now. I meant an ODE with derivatives that apply on the fourier transform functions with respect to the frequency variable. That's different from the case you describe i believe?